# Custom protocol handler does not work in MS Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, protocol-handler

We register custom protocol handler for our application.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp]
@="URL: TestApp Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"wscript\" \"C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\TestService\\CustomTestProtocolHandler.vbs\" \"%1\""
```

Both Chrome and Explorer can start this custom protocol handler.
But it does not work from MS Edge.
Should I perform some additional configuration to enable custom protocol in Edge?
Or custom protocol handler will not work from MS Edge at all?

**UPDATE:**
It works for me if I use "EditFlags"=dword:00210000 value:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp]
@="URL: TestApp Protocol"
"EditFlags"=dword:00210000
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\testapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"wscript\" \"C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\TestService\\CustomTestProtocolHandler.vbs\" \"%1\""
```

FTA_OpenIsSafe - 0x00010000
FTA_SafeForElevation - 0x00200000
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762506(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found to make it work in MS Edge was to point the open command to an intermediate bat file. My registry entry look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\magnet]
@="URL:Magnet Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\magnet\shell]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\magnet\shell\open]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\magnet\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\Program Files\\PowerShell Scripts\\HandleMagnetTransmission.bat\" \"%1\""
```

I don't know why MS Edge refuses to call any executable file directly as a protocol handler. I tried notepad.exe for example, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Same thing happening on one computer (for a customer). My workstation opens the needed program correctly but I have seen another computer with Windows 10 and MS Edge not opening this program through custom protocol, while other browsers ON THE SAME WORKSTATION does open. Not sure why (yet).

Comment: I am seeing this same thing... has anyone figured out why this is?

Comment: It works for me in MS Edge if I add "EditFlags"=dword:00200000 value. See update.

Comment: "EditFlags"=dword:00210000